# Users do not have access after AD group is inserted in SharePoint 2016 Group

Tags: permissions, active-directory, groups

Domain administrator created an AD group with some users in it and we inserted it in SP group, but users don't have access. After three attempts they get access denied.

Comment: If the admin made the group and added people in the same day, the users might need to log off and log back in for the changes to take effect on their account

Comment: to log off from where? Domain administrator made the AD group and added the users in that group and then we added the AD group in SP group.

Comment: On their computers, each user might need to log out of Windows and then back in. A lot of AD changes don't reflect immediately and require a log out/in to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior at one of our customers and we found that it took up to 24 hours before the AD-group was accessible in SharePoint. To overcome this, we created another SharePoint group, set the permissions on the group and added the effected users to the group.

The day after we checked with one effected user, removed her from the second group, and she had access then.

I don't know why, but as a workaround it's doable.

Comment: thanks for your answer Benny. I will give it a try and get to you soon.